# Is a Rust function which generates a String of SQL vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: sql, rust

I have the following Rust function which creates a `String` of an SQL statement for a SQLite database.

```
fn add_repo_statement(repo: &Repo) -> String {
    format!("INSERT INTO repositories (name, scm, path)
            VALUES ({}, {}, {})", repo.name, repo.scm, repo.path)
}
```

I'm not very familiar with SQL injection; is such a Rust function vulnerable to SQL injection? If yes, what exactly is the problem and possible solution?

Comment: In addition to being invalid syntactically, this is 100% vulnerable to SQL injection. You **must** use a driver with support for prepared statements with placeholder values.

Comment: I looked hard, but didn't find the syntax error. Where is it?

Comment: If you just want to create the SQL query string and don't need to execute it with a connection to an actual database, the https://docs.rs/sql-builder/latest/sql_builder/index.html crate is the way to go.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes, this is vulnerable

This isn't Rust-specific or SQLite-specific; if you generate a SQL string using user-provided parameters in *any* language for *any* database, *it is vulnerable*.

> I'm not very familiar with SQL injection

There's simply no excuse to remain in this state. [Go out there and learn](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection); we will wait...

---

The TL;DR is that a malicious user can specify values for `repo.name`, `repo.scm`, or `repo.path` that, when combined, generates SQL that does not do what you want:

```
fn main() {
    let sql = format!(
        "INSERT INTO repositories (name, scm, path) VALUES ({}, {}, {})",
        r#""hi", "from", "injection"); DROP TABLE repositories; --"#, 
        "",
        ""
    );
    println!("{}", sql);
}
```

```sql
INSERT INTO repositories (name, scm, path) VALUES ("hi", "from", "injection"); DROP TABLE repositories; --, , )
```

The fix is to use appropriate quoting/parameterization mechanisms. I'd encourage you to use an access abstraction layer like [Diesel](http://diesel.rs/). Doing so, your code would look something like this untested code:

```
insert_into(repositories)
    .values((name.eq(repo.name), scm.eq(repo.scm), path.eq(repo.path)))
    .execute(conn);
```

Or you can make it nicer as

```
insert_into(repositories)
    .values(repo)
    .execute(conn);
```

If you don't want to use Diesel for whatever reason, direct drivers [like rusqlite](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.13.0/rusqlite/) provide similar mechanisms, shown in this untested code:

```
conn.execute(
    "INSERT INTO repositories (name, scm, path) VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3)",
    &[&repo.name, &repo.scm, &repo.path],
).unwrap();
```